# How can one shutdown nginx and cron when they are monitored with supervisord?

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am trying to automate deployment of a webapplication, updating the app requires shutting down cron and nginx.

Problem is, when I stop the process via `service nginx stop` and `service cron stop`, these are restarted by supervisord.

There is no init.d script for supervisord, furthermore I am not certain if one is to use supervisorctl to manage services.

What is the proper approach?

Comment: Why is this tagged [docker]?  Are the processes running inside a Docker container?  If so, why don't you just shut down the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `supervisorctl` for this. But that would only work if you have `supervisorctl` configured in your supervisorconfig

So you need to use

```
$ supervisorctl status
```

This will give you the names of the services and then you can use

```
$ supervisorctl stop nginx-program
$ supervisorctl stop cron-program
```

That is how you should be handling it